# TeraCopy not being used as default copy handler

Tags: windows-7, teracopy

I have TeraCopy installed on all my computers and it is set to be the default copy handler.  However, since my last OS reinstall, it does not seem to want to act as the default.  Seems about 80-90% of the time, when I drag and drop a file it is preferentially using the default Windows copy method.  I have not noticed any pattern as to when it lets me use TeraCopy.  I have an older computer that still seems to be working as expected (no idea on its Windows or TeraCopy update history).

I can still open TeraCopy manually and drop in some files then select the destination, but I want it to go automatically.  I have tried disabling/enabling the default handler, as well as uninstalling and reinstalling, but it still seems to prefer the Windows version.  A right-click drag and drop should offer me the TeraCopy and Windows versions of the copy/move procedures, but it is currently only showing the Windows one.

Anyone run into this before?  Is there any way for me to force it into the default handler or at least on the right-click version?

Comment: Is it completely random or does it, for example, stop or start working only on reboots? Have you tried to disable your antivirus and reboot?

Comment: It's random enough that I haven't found a pattern.  A reboot does not appear to fix it (just tried that before posting).  I have not tried disabling the AV, but it seems to me that this was happening before I installed the AV after my last reinstall (about a month ago).

Comment: I'd give disabling AV a try. Also, you can use [Autoruns](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb963902.aspx) to review what DLLs are loaded with `explorer`. Maybe something is conflicting.

Comment: Suspending or exiting AV made no change.  Even tried re-registering the copy handler while AV was off but no change.

Comment: TeraCopy has an option somewhere in settings, which, if turned on, will make Windows use the default copy handler if Scroll Lock is on and TeraCopy if Scroll Lock is off. Future users encountering this problem might like to check to see if they have that setting turned on.

Answer (score 1):

Reinstalling the program as a "normal" installation into the Program Files directory (as opposed to a portable installation) fixed the problem for me.

Answer (score -2):

You can change between TeraCopy and the default Windows copy function by launching TeraCopy, rightclicking on its interface, hitting Preferences, and toggling "Use TeraCopy as default copy handler".

Comment: It sounds like OP has already done this.